# console.log a json value

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I need to console.log this value:

[image] the

Specifically location which is under geometry

right now I able to print this entire set of data with this javascript code:

```
var url='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&key=APIKEYHERE';

function Get(url){
    var Httpreq = new XMLHttpRequest(); // a new request
    Httpreq.open("GET", url, false);
    Httpreq.send(null);
    return Httpreq.responseText;          
}

var json_obj = JSON.parse(Get(url));

console.log(json_obj.results);
```

This code will not work for anyone who is trying to live test because you need an API Key.

The problem that I run into is that when I try and

```
console.log(json_obj.results.0)
```

I get this error:

[image]

Does anyone know how to print this value?

Comment: try `console.log(json_obj.results[0])`

Comment: use object bracket notation in such case ... `[0]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access `i`th element of an array:

```
results[i];
```

So you should use:

```
console.log(json_obj.results[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this: (untested)
`console.log(json_obj.results[0].geometry.location)`

Comment: Yes, that was exactly what I need thank you!!